# are tags perceived as additive when filtering questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was wondering when asking a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461105/how-to-nest-structured-filtered-queries) whether the tags are perceived by the readers as being connected with a `AND`or an `OR`?

My question was about elasticsearch but the code used in the question was Python. The code was there for illustration and documentation but the essence of the question is on elasticsearch. Code in Java or whatever could have been used without changing the spirit of the question.

Still, there was Python code in the question.

In other words should the tags reflect the verbatim content of the question, or just the spirit?

Answer (score 2):

It is up to people following the [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) tag to decide wether or not the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag matters to them or not. The question will be listed under both tags.

If your question isn't really about the Python code and Python experts won't really be able to help out, then there may be little point in the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) being present, but on the whole this doesn't really matter all that much.